# LINQ to entity, wrong join type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a query that looks like so....

```
var q = Dal.TBLINVENTORies.Where(i => i.SHOWIT);
q = q.Where(i => i.dtStart < DateTime.Now || i.dtStart == null);
q = q.Where(i => i.dtEnd > DateTime.Now || i.dtEnd == null);
q = q.Where(i => i.sSystem.Contains("OE"));
q = q.Where(i => i.WS_ActiveList_ID == 0 || i.tblWS_ActiveList.WS_MasterList_ID == 16);
var test2 = q.ToList();
```

Immediately before the "ToList()", if I examine the query, I get the following sql (more or less)

```
SELECT [Extent1].*
FROM  [dbo].[TBLINVENTORY] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblWS_ActiveList] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[WS_ActiveList_ID] = [Extent2].[ID]
WHERE ([Extent1].[SHOWIT] = 1) 
AND (([Extent1].[dtStart] <  CAST( SysDateTime() AS datetime2)) OR ([Extent1].[dtStart] IS NULL)) 
AND (([Extent1].[dtEnd] >  CAST( SysDateTime() AS datetime2)) OR ([Extent1].[dtEnd] IS NULL)) 
AND ([Extent1].[sSystem] LIKE '%OE%') 
AND ([Extent1].[WS_ActiveList_ID] = 0  OR [Extent2].[WS_MasterList_ID] = 16)
```

Unfortunately, this is not what I need, because relationship between "Inventory" and "ActiveList" is not really 1-to-Many, but Zero-to-Many (I'm not sure I'm using the correct terms).  Basically, An inventory item might or might not have a related "ActiveList".

If I change that raw SQL to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, instead of an `INNER JOIN`, the SQL returns the values I expect.

What is needed to force the LEFT OUTER JOIN?

I've tried the recommended solution from [Linq to entities - One to many relationship - need left outer join instead of cross join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483489) , but,

`var q2 = from inv in Dal.TBLINVENTORies from al in inv.tblWS_ActiveList`

returns an error:

`Error  65  An expression of type 'xxxx.DAL.tblWS_ActiveList' is not allowed in a subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<xxxx.DAL.TBLINVENTORY>'.  Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'.`

I wonder if my link/relationship is constructed incorrectly?  Any other ideas?

Thanks!

#### EDIT :: Additional Data

```
-- create foreign key, but don't enforce on existing values
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblInventory]  --the ONE Table
    WITH NOCHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK__tblInventory.WS_ActiveList_ID__tblWS_ActiveList.ID] 
        FOREIGN KEY([WS_ActiveList_ID]) 
            REFERENCES [dbo].[tblWS_ActiveList] ([ID])    --the MANY Table
        NOT FOR REPLICATION
GO

-- disable enforcement of the foreign key, but leave it in place (virtual key)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblInventory]  
    NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK__tblInventory.WS_ActiveList_ID__tblWS_ActiveList.ID] 
GO
```

and the definition of WS_ActiveList_ID:

```
[WS_ActiveList_ID] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_TBLINVENTORY_WS_ActiveList_ID] DEFAULT (0),
```

Comment: Can you show how the relationship to WS_ActiveList is configured? Is it a nullable relationship or are you using 0 to represent a null relationship?

Comment: 0 to represent.  What data do you want me to dig up and show?  I'll grab the SQL definition of the relationship....lemme know if you needed something else.

Comment: Try changing the FK property to be Nullable<int>

Comment: I have some legacy concerns with making that change (I presume you're saying to make the `tblInventory.WS_ActiveList_ID` in the SQL definition not, `NOT NULL` ?

Comment: EF assumes that 0 or 1 to many uses a null to represent 0.  I know of no way to make a join work in EF where you have a value of 0 to represent no join.  Although you could likely formulate the join to exclude 0's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that you've turned off the referential integrity checks in your database.

Apart from the obvious problem of bad data, this won't work with EF.

By far the best option is to make `WS_ActiveList_ID` nullable, update your data to change all the `0`s to `NULL`s and turn the constraint back on.

If you can't do that, I think you'll have to generate a SQL statement as a string and execute it with `dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>` ( [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) )

Comment: :D  Yes, I figured someone would comment on this.  The "problem" is that this is an old (12years or older) legacy system, which never had any key relationships in the first place, let alone RI.

Comment: ....Now that I'm re-writing portions of the application with asp.net mvc with EF, I'm starting to add them in, as needed, but, only partially, because of all the legacy data thats already in there that would otherwise fail....Someday 'soon' we'll start fixing the data side, and adding in the RI, but for now, this is what we've got.

Comment: Can you point out that not fixing the db is making more work for you, which will be thrown away when the db **is** eventually fixed?

Comment: I'm not *wholly* convinced of that, but, considering the time constraints I'm currently under to bring this project to completion, I can't spare the delay that fixing it would entail